# Quartz.NET Job Lifetime

Tags: quartz.net

I'm using Quartz.NET and I'm having trouble finding documentation regarding the lifetime of a job.

Is a new instance of the job class created each time the job is run, or will an existing instance be reused?

What about if the job is currently running when the trigger fires again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each firing of a trigger creates a new instance of a job. If two triggers overlap, two instances will be created.

These instances aren't pooled, once the job is done, they become eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Easy enough. Thanks. Is there any documentation you could point me to? I spent some time hunting through the java docs as well as the limited .NET documentation, but couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: @RMD: unfortunately I can't find any documentation wrt. to that, it's just based on my experience.